# Facing issues while creating a mock of below ParentChildDetail class

Tags: java, junit, powermock, easymock

I have to mock the below ParentChildDetail class.

In the class shown here, only one constructor is available which is a parametrized constructor. But constructor is calling `initialise()` method. So while mocking the object its calling again `initialise()` method which will hit the database.

But I have to manually create the data for JUNIT test

```
    public class ParentChildDetail
    {
        private final String ALL_HQL = "hql query to fetch parent and child";
        private Map<Integer, Set<Child>> parentChildMapping = null;

        private Integer Id;
        private DateTime date;

        public ParentChildDetail( Integer Id, DateTime date ) throws HibernateException
        {
            this.Id = Id;
            this.date = date;
            initialise();
        }

        private void initialise() throws HibernateException
        {
            String[] paramNames =
            { "Id", "effectiveDate" };
            Object[] paramValues =
            { Id, date };
            List<Child> Childs = HibernateSession.query( ALL_HQL, paramNames, paramValues );

            for ( Child child : Childs )
            {
                if ( parentChildCache.get( child.getParentId() ) == null )
                {
                    Set<Child> val = new HashSet<>();
                    val.add( child );
                    parentChildCache.put( child.getParentId(), val );
                }
                else
                {
                    parentChildCache.get( child.getParentId() ).add( child );
                }
            }
        }

        public Map<Integer, Set<Child>> getParentChildCache()
        {
            return parentChildCache;
        }

        public void setParentChildCache( Map<Integer, Set<Child>> parentChildCache )
        {
            this.parentChildCache = parentChildCache;
        }
    }
```

but while mocking the parameterized constructor its again calling initialise()

Here the sample code I am writing to mock

```
    Method initialize=ParentChildDetail.class.getDeclaredMethod( "initialise", noparams );
    Object[] args={1,new DateTime(new Date( "01/01/2017" ))};
    Constructor<ParentChildDetail> c=ParentChildDetail.class.getConstructor(Integer.class,org.joda.time.DateTime.class);
    ConstructorArgs constructorArgs = new ConstructorArgs(c,args);
    ParentChildDetail p= PowerMock.createMock( ParentChildDetail.class, constructorArgs,initialize );
```

but I'm getting this error at LAST LINE

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate mock calling constructor: Exception in constructor
>
> at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory.createProxy(ClassProxyFactory.java:219)
>   at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:129)
>   at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:114)
>   at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.doCreateMock(PowerMock.java:2220)
>   at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.doMock(PowerMock.java:2163)
>   at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.createMock(PowerMock.java:108)
>   at com.subex.rocps.routingratecalculator.ParentChildTest.getTrnIdOperatorMDLMap(ParentChildTest.java:88)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>   at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>               at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>               at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
>               at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>               at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>               at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
>               at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
>               at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
>               at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
>               at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
>               at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
>               at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>               at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>               at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>               at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>               at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>               at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>           Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
>               at com.subex.spark.database.hibernate.util.HibernateSession.checkInitialised(HibernateSession.java:288)
>               at com.subex.spark.database.hibernate.util.HibernateSession.getSessionFactory(HibernateSession.java:254)
>               at com.subex.spark.database.hibernate.util.HibernateSession.query(HibernateSession.java:298)
>               at com.subex.rocps.routingratecalculator.util.ParentElementCacheCreator.initialise(ParentElementCacheCreator.java:41)
>               at com.subex.rocps.routingratecalculator.util.ParentElementCacheCreator.(ParentElementCacheCreator.java:31)
>               at com.subex.rocps.routingratecalculator.util.ParentElementCacheCreator$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ba31f8d9.()
>               at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>               at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory.createProxy(ClassProxyFactory.java:207)
>               ... 29 more

Comment: i would say its a bad practice to have a constructor call a method which does make a database call. you should rework your code and outsource this database call. if you can try to use hibernate for the database access

Comment: Beyond that: and why exactly is  `createMock(YourClass.class)` not "good enough"? Meaning: why do you want to run that constructor. You are **mocking** the class, so why do you care about the *real* code of the real class? What is the point of mocking, when you are still affected by the "real implementation"?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Agreed with u... But I got a work to do JUnit for older classes of the project. So cant change the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters said, the approach of calling a data access layer as a side effect of constructing a class may be anti pattern. At any rate it makes **unit testing** that class difficult. In this case the difficulty arises because `ParentChildDetail()` calls `ParentChildDetail.initialise()` which in turn calls `HibernateSession.query()` and since that's a static method, testing it is a little bit tricky.

The following test case uses EasyMock (because that's what your question is tagged with) and PowerMock to facilitate instantiation of `ParentChildDetail`:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(HibernateSession.class)
public class ParentChildDetailTest {

  @Test
  public void testSomething() {
    PowerMock.mockStatic(HibernateSession.class);

    Integer id = 1234;
    DateTime date = new DateTime();

    // not sure what you want to retrieve here, maybe nothing, maybe some particular children so 
    // that you can test the behaviour of the initialise() method
    List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

    expect(HibernateSession.query(anyString(), (String[]) anyObject(), (Object[]) anyObject()))
        .andReturn(children);

    PowerMock.replay(HibernateSession.class);

    ParentChildDetail parentChildDetail = new ParentChildDetail(id, date);

    // parentChildDetail has now been successfully constructed/initialised and it is available for use in your test ...

  }
}
```

This code is functional for EasyMock v3.4, PowerMock v1.6.1+ and Junit 4.12

Detail's on mocking with PowerMock [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockStatic).

Details on integrating JUnit, EasyMock and PowerMock [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/EasyMock-Maven).